# How to assign key,value to map[interface{}]interface{}?

Tags: dictionary, go

```
var cache atomic.Value

func setResToCache(res *utils.InterfaceMap) error {
    resMap := res.ToInterfaceMap()
    val := resMap[constant.key] // constant.key is a constant string
    val, ok := val.(string)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion failed")
    }
    someRes := model.someRes{
        Title:    val,
    }
    Cache.Store(someRes)
    return nil
}
```

about utils.InterfaceMap

```
type InterfaceMap sync.Map

//ToInterfaceMap
func (im *InterfaceMap) ToInterfaceMap() map[interface{}]interface{} {
    iim := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    m := (*sync.Map)(im)
    m.Range(func(k, v interface{}) bool {
        iim[k] = v
        return true
    })
    return iim
}
```

I have some code similar to the above, and I have a problem when I want to write a unit test.

```
    {
        name: "test",
        args: args{
            res: &utils.InterfaceMap{
                // How to assign k,v here
            },
        },
        wantErr: false,
    },
```

How to how to assign key,value to `map[interface{}]interface{}`?

It is actually `map[string]string`, so I use assert, but the parameter passed in is `map[interface{}]interface{}`.

I want to add some `string: string` to map so that I can successfully test the code.

Comment: what are the `key values` you need to add to the map? and what is *utils.InterfaceMap ?

Comment: To define `InterfaceMap`, you need the definition for `sync.Map`. `sync.Map` may not be a `map[interface{}]interface{}` given `ToInterfaceMap()` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create simple function in your test file to input `map[string]string` and inside the function, write those values to `sync.Map` and cast it to `InterfaceMap` type and return the reference. Example is as below.

```
func createMockInterfaceMap(in map[string]string) *utils.InterfaceMap{
    mockMap := sync.Map{}
    for key, value := range in {
        mockMap.Store(key, value)
    }

    iMap := utils.InterfaceMap(mockMap)

    return &iMap
}
```

```
{
    name: "test",
    args: args{
        res: createMockInterfaceMap(map[string]string{
            `key1`:`value1`,
            `key2`:`value2`,
        }),
    },
    wantErr: false,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass in a `map[interface{}]interface{}`, it will need to be defined as such.

You can convert a `map[string]string` to a `map[interface{}]interface{}` using something like the following:

```golang
func MapConvert(mss map[string]string) map[interface{}]interface{} {
    ifaceMap := map[interface{}]interface{}{}
    for k, v := range mss {
        ifaceMap[k] = v
    }
    return ifaceMap
}
```

Here's an example using a type definition:

```golang
type InterfaceMap map[interface{}]interface{}

func MapConvert(mss map[string]string) *InterfaceMap {
    ifaceMap := InterfaceMap{}
    for k, v := range mss {
        ifaceMap[k] = v
    }
    return &ifaceMap
}
```

Here's a full running example:

https://play.golang.org/p/UPKqqZnFis-